# Correct way to author Vue components that rely on parent build tools

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

> I imagine this problem would apply to other frameworks that have a bit of a plugin/component ecosystem about them that rely on specific build tools (React components with JSX, etc). Vue is just my use-case.

I have authored several Vue components in the form of single `.vue` files which are published to NPM. The `package.json` for these component does not list any dependencies, as they themselves are intended to function within a parent project that uses webpack, vue-loader, sass-loader, etc. [This is an example of one such component](https://github.com/MartyWallace/vue-keyboard).

I am unsure about the best way to declare that these components rely on the parent package having said build tools. I am not confident that `devDependencies` is the correct place for them as the component itself has no development step that relies on these. `peerDependencies` seems more suitable but again I am not confident this properly matches what I am trying to achieve.

Looking through many of the components on the [awesome-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue) repository I can't see any use of `peerDependencies` and the `devDependencies` seem relevant to the development of the particular components themselves.

What is the correct way to author these components? It's almost like I need something like "`peerDevDependencies`".

Comment: Could you distribute them as a plugin?

Comment: @BertEvans I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Consider vue-router. It includes components. It is distributed as a plugin. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: @BertEvans Oh sure I see what you mean. In my case these are components as [described here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and I guess the meta (information about how to use and where they're appropriate) of these components seems lacking when distributed over NPM.

Comment: Could you not compile the single file component yourself and distribute the compiled version? Agree about documentation though, you're pretty much reliant on whatever a package writer has provided.

Comment: I could distribute the compiled version but that doesn't seem to be the standard as I look through other popular components. I suspect this question could be broadened out to "how can I distribute any general JavaScript package that relies on webpack, sass-loader, or any other series of build tools?".

Answer (score 1):

Most component are, unfortunately distributed already compiled.

In my opinion the best way to distribute a component is to write as `main` the raw `.vue` file of the component.

You shouldn’t specify to use any particular tool, developers that pick up your package should be free to use the tool they want, be it Browserify or Rollup (or Webpack). The raw `.vue` format allows them to compile the `.vue` component with whatever tool they want and using whatever Vue version they want (within a range of course).

Moreover what I like to do is give the users the possibility to use the component straight away, even inside a browser, with just Vue as a `<script>` dependency. For this you would have to compile it and, yes, specify `Vue` as a `peerDependency` in the sense that it’s needed in the page.

You can put meta information in the `package.json` to tell CDN to pick up the compiled version when inside the browser, this is very handy so the user just specify the name of the package without worrying about the file name or version.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd like to push all the compiled code to the repository, that seems like a huge mess (although you're right, a lot of projects do this). Providing just the `.vue` file so that others can use it however they like is what I have now but [this issue](https://github.com/MartyWallace/vue-keyboard/issues/10) that someone opened made me curious if there was actually a way to add more information about the intended or at least minimal build process for the component.

Comment: As said, you should not constrain the developers in the tools they use, so it would be preferable to just not include any information in the package.json. Maybe the readme is a better place?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking only as a consumer of Vue.js components, I think specifying your build dependencies as `peerDependencies` is the best solution. You are using what is a pretty standard build pipeline, but I think that having them specified is important. These are not strictly devDependencies or dependencies depending on where they are going to be compiled by the end user.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you use `"module"` property on the `package.json` for the raw vue file, and the `"main"` as the compiled one. `module` is a property getting standardized and webpack and rollup already understand it.

For more info see s[etting up multiplatform npm packages article](http://2ality.com/2017/04/setting-up-multi-platform-packages.html).

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have a play around over the next couple of days and see how it works out - thanks!

Comment: I think you mean the opposite